# Using HtmlAgilityPack to get a specific row and column data

Tags: c#, xpath, xml-parsing, html-agility-pack

This is my table

```
<table class="DataRows" frame="myFrames" rules="Standard" width="100%">

  <colgroup><col width="70" align="CENTER">
  <col width="200" align="LEFT">
  <col width="80" align="LEFT">
  <col align="LEFT">
  <col align="RIGHT">

  </colgroup><thead>

  <col width="70" align="CENTER">
  <col width="200" align="LEFT">
  <col width="80" align="LEFT">
  <col align="LEFT">
  <col align="RIGHT">

  <thead>

  <tr>
    <td valign="TOP"><span class="classicBold"> 20 </span> Kg.
    <td class="BOLD" valign="TOP" nowrap="">
      PA Passion Foods Inc.
    <td class="BOLD">Fax:
    <td>
      222-555666
    <td class="BOLD">
      Processed foods and juices

  <tr>
    <td><a target="_blank" href="">See on Map </a>
    <td>
      120 NW 157TH AVE 
    <td class="BOLD">Warehouse Hours:
    <td colspan="2">


  <tr>
    <td>
    <td><span class="BOLD">
      Jacksonville,
      </span>
      FL 300000
    <td class="BOLD">Url:
    <td colspan="2">
      <a target="_blank" href="">PA Passion</a>
      &nbsp&nbsp
      <span class="BOLD">E-mail:</span>
      zoro@xyz.com

  <tr>
    <td>
    <td class="REDBOLD" colspan="4">


  <tr>
    <td>
    <td colspan="4" align="LEFT">Franchisee for:<span class="BOLD">
 Nutrella


</span>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <td colspan="4" align="LEFT">Franchisee for:<span class="BOLD">
APPLE Foods, Constants
</span>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <td colspan="4" align="LEFT"><span class="BOLD">

</span>

  <tr>
    <td>
    <td colspan="4" align="LEFT">We service:<span class="BOLD">
All occasions and hospitality services
</span>

  <tr>
    <td>
    <td colspan="4" align="LEFT">We sell :<span class="BOLD">
----
</span>

</td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></td></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I am looping through each node in my Html document using the code below

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlAgilityPackDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[contains(@class,'DataRows')]"))
{

}
```

When I use the following

```
node.SelectSingleNode(".//tr[1]/td[1]").InnerHtml
```

I get the following html

```
<span class="classicBold"> 20 </span> Kg.
        <td class="BOLD" valign="TOP" nowrap="">
          PA Passion Foods Inc.
        <td class="BOLD">Fax:
        <td>
          222-555666
        <td class="BOLD">
          Processed foods and juices

      <tr>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="">See on Map </a>
        <td>
          120 NW 157TH AVE 
        <td class="BOLD">Warehouse Hours:
        <td colspan="2">


      <tr>
        <td>
        <td><span class="BOLD">
          Jacksonville,
          </span>
          FL 300000
        <td class="BOLD">Url:
        <td colspan="2">
          <a target="_blank" href="">PA Passion</a>
          &nbsp&nbsp
          <span class="BOLD">E-mail:</span>
          zoro@xyz.com

      <tr>
        <td>
        <td class="REDBOLD" colspan="4">


      <tr>
        <td>
        <td colspan="4" align="LEFT">Franchisee for:<span class="BOLD">
     Nutrella


    </span>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <td colspan="4" align="LEFT">Franchisee for:<span class="BOLD">
    APPLE Foods, Constants
    </span>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <td colspan="4" align="LEFT"><span class="BOLD">

    </span>

      <tr>
        <td>
        <td colspan="4" align="LEFT">We service:<span class="BOLD">
    All occasions and hospitality services
    </span>

      <tr>
        <td>
        <td colspan="4" align="LEFT">We sell :<span class="BOLD">
    ----
    </span>

    </td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></td>
```

How do I extract the address **120 NW 157TH AVE**  from this ?

When I tried using

```
node.SelectSingleNode(".//td[@class='BOLD'][4]/preceding-sibling::td").InnerText;
```

I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is a mess tags are overlapping i suggest you use text nodes as your identifiers rather than indices for example

```
.//td[./a[contains(text(),'See on Map')]]/td/text()
```

to get

`120 NW 157TH AVE`

Here is a full example that gets you everything

```
    var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[contains(@class,'DataRows')]");

    var name = table.SelectSingleNode(".//td[@class='BOLD']/text()").InnerText.Trim();
    var fax = table.SelectSingleNode(".//td[contains(text(),'Fax')]/td/text()").InnerText.Trim();
    var email = table.SelectSingleNode(".//span[contains(text(),'E-mail')]/following-sibling::text()").InnerText.Trim();
    var address = table.SelectSingleNode(".//td[./a[contains(text(),'See on Map')]]/td/text()").InnerText.Trim();
    var city = table.SelectSingleNode(".//tr[./td/a[contains(text(),'See on Map')]]//tr/td/td/span").InnerText.Trim(',');
    var zip = table.SelectSingleNode(".//tr[./td/a[contains(text(),'See on Map')]]//tr/td/td/span/following-sibling::text()").InnerText.Trim();
```

Note because of how messy your html is the xpaths has to be as messy, trying to access the `tr` element by index won't work because all tr elements are children of the previous `tr`, what is `.//tr[4]` in a normal table is `.//tr/tr/tr/tr` in your table.

Comment: The funny thing is that when I see the html on the site, it doesn't seem to have any issues but when I load it using .. SelectNodes("//table[contains(@class,'DataRows')]"  and call its InnerHtml, then it seems to take off the ending tags of rows and columns ..I dont know how this is happening.

Comment: @user20358 that because browsers try to fix faulty html and are really good at that, one reason to write faulty html like the above is to make harder to scrape, browsers are good at fixing it anyway.

Comment: aha!.. I knew it couldn't be magic! Thanks for the tip there. btw, I got it working using the loop also. it works perfectly well that way too